# Selenium WebDriver, How to run/connect next class

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I'm new to Selenium Webdriver, I have a few question :

First, I have 2 class, 'Login.java' and 'SelectCity.java

Class 1 : Login.java

- invalidLogin
- validLogin

Class 2 : SelectCity.java

For now, in Login.java I wrote

```
@After

public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    driver.close();
}
```

which mean the browser will closed after finish run right?

Here is my question :

1. How to make after I run validLogin, it will continue to run the next class (SelectCity.java)?
   Is it possible to do that?
2. How to make last browser (which test valid login) didn't get close?

My current Login.java class :

```
      public class Login  extends SelectCityAfterLogin{

  private WebDriver driver;
  private String baseUrl;
  private StringBuffer verificationErrors = new StringBuffer();

  @Before
  public void setUp() throws Exception {
    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    baseUrl = "http://mysite/";
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  }


  @Test 
  public void testLoginInvalidPass() throws Exception {
    driver.get(baseUrl + "/mysite/login.aspx");
    driver.findElement(By.id("txtUsername")).sendKeys("user1");
    driver.findElement(By.id("txtPassword")).sendKeys("somePassword");
    driver.findElement(By.id("lbLogin")).click();

    try {
      assertEquals("Invalid User or Password", driver.findElement(By.id("lblError")).getText());
    } catch (Error e) {
      verificationErrors.append(e.toString());
    }
  }

  @Test 
  public void testLoginInvalidUsername() throws Exception {
    driver.get(baseUrl + "/mysite/login.aspx");
    driver.findElement(By.id("txtUsername")).sendKeys("username");
    driver.findElement(By.id("txtPassword")).sendKeys("somepassword");
    driver.findElement(By.id("lbLogin")).click();

    try {
      assertEquals("Invalid User or Password", driver.findElement(By.id("lblError")).getText());
    } catch (Error e) {
      verificationErrors.append(e.toString());
    }
  }

  @Test 
  public void testLoginNoUsername() throws Exception {
    driver.get(baseUrl + "/mysite/login.aspx");
    driver.findElement(By.id("txtUsername")).sendKeys("");
    driver.findElement(By.id("txtPassword")).sendKeys("somePassword");
    driver.findElement(By.id("lbLogin")).click();

    try {
      assertEquals("Please fill username and password.", driver.findElement(By.id("lblError")).getText());
    } catch (Error e) {
      verificationErrors.append(e.toString());
    }
  }

  @Test 
  public void testLoginNoPassword() throws Exception {
    driver.get(baseUrl + "/mysite/login.aspx");
    driver.findElement(By.id("txtUsername")).sendKeys("username");
    driver.findElement(By.id("txtPassword")).sendKeys("");
    driver.findElement(By.id("lbLogin")).click();

    try {
      assertEquals("Please fill username and password.", driver.findElement(By.id("lblError")).getText());
    } catch (Error e) {
      verificationErrors.append(e.toString());
    }
  }

  @Test 
    public void testLoginValid() throws Exception{
    //SelectRoleAfterLogin selectRole = SelectRoleAfterLogin();  

    driver.get(baseUrl + "/mysite/login.aspx");
    driver.findElement(By.id("txtUsername")).sendKeys("myUsername");
    driver.findElement(By.id("txtPassword")).sendKeys("password");
    driver.findElement(By.id("lbLogin")).click();
    Thread.sleep(3000);     
  }
```

}

Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can run selectcity after login

You should Extend your First class to Second class

In your Login.java extend it to selectcity java like below

```
Public class login extends Selectcity {
```

After your validlogin

create a new instance for selectcity (If you are using @test, create the below in that)

```
selectcity test = new selectcity()
Once after your valid login do the following
test.(will fetch you the methods available in selectcity.java)
```

By this way you can call once class to another.

Let me know if this helps

**UPDATE :**

if selectcityAfterlogin in `public class Login  extends **SelectCityAfterLogin**` is your second class name, then you are creating an incorrect object i guess

In your public login class please check whether your are extending  the proper second class name

In @test method

```
@Test 
    public void testLoginValid() throws Exception{
    //SelectRoleAfterLogin selectRole = SelectRoleAfterLogin();
```

it should be

```
SelectCityAfterLogin selectrole = new SelectCityAfterLogin()
selectrole.(will fetch you the methods of second city)
```

Please let me know if this helps.

One better solution would be to create multiple methods than multiple @test. You can call these to single @test suite.

Comment: Thx for your reply :) I already type for public class login extends.

But when I type selectCity test= .....

This "The method SelectCity() is undefined for the type Login" show up. What does it mean?

Comment: @user3558620 : Can you please update the question with your code on how you are trying to extend it, so that it will be helpful to us in helping you find where the issue is and resolve it

Comment: Hi, I've added my current Login.java class :)

Comment: @user3558620 : I have posted an update. Please let me know if this helps

Comment: Hooray I get it!! Thank you so much and thank you for giving me advice to create multiple methods than Test, thank you so so much

Comment: Srriram, sorry to bother you again and this OOT question.

Can I create :

WebElement tbUsername = driver.findElement(By.id("txtUsername"));

WebElement tbPassword = driver.findElement(By.id("txtPassword"));

if(tbUsername.sendkeys!= ("[correct username]") && tbPassword.sendkeys!=([correct password])){

assertEquals("Please try again", driver.findElement(By.id("lblError")).getText());
     
}

Comment: I've succesfully manage this, I'm using data-driven to create test about invalid login, thank you for want to help me :)

Answer (score 0):

> I am assuming, you have 2 classes 'Login.java' and 'SelectCity.java'
>   as follows:

Class 1 : Login.java

```
public void invalidLogin (WebDriver driver){

//some operations

}

public void validLogin (WebDriver driver){

//some operations

}
```

Class 2 : SelectCity.java

```
public void selectCity (Webdriver Driver){

//some operations

}
```

Class 3: LoginAndSelectCity.java

```
public static void main(String args []){

WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

Login.validLogin(driver);
SelectCity.selectCity(driver);

}
```

*If all classes should be in same package then only it works else you need to import packages or create new child to do inheritance of the classes.*

Comment: Thx for your reply :) So, I should create one more class name LoginAndSelectCity.java? My classes are in same package. When I tried type for class 3, this warn show up "The method validLogin(WebDriver) is undefined for the type  LoginAndSelectCity". Should I make new method in class 3?

Comment: No need to define method again.
I had just updated the Class 3 with some missing arguments, please try that one.